# Linux: How to delete a lot of files?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I would like to delete 100k files and I use:

```
rm *.tif
```

Then I got:

```
bash: /usr/bin/rm: Argument list too long
```

So I tried:

```
find . -name '*.shp' | xargs rm -f
```

Then I got:

```
find: ‘./inaccessible’: Permission denied
```

How to solve the problem?

Comment: This is more a question for https://superuser.com/ or https://serverfault.com/

Comment: That's just a warning; you obviously cannot remove files you don't have access to. If you don't want your `find` command to try to visit subdirectories, add `--maxdepth 1`.  Going forward, please search before asking; these are very common beginner questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `sudo find . -name '*.shp' -print -exec rm {} \;` and let me know if it worked.

Regards.

Comment: Didn't work, find: ‘./inaccessible’: Permission denied.

Comment: Ok, I just edited the post.

Comment: The same, find: ‘./gvfs’: Permission denied